# blueprint 1.0.2 can't create inner bean in the War bundle

Tags: osgi, blueprint

i want to upgrade virgo to 3.6.2,however i met a strange things. the war bundle can't start. the root reason is cna't load class in the war bundle. but there is no this issue in the blueprint 1.0.0.M1.
it is great if someone give me some suggestions. the log message is as following:

[2013-08-28 10:44:21.136] WARN  region-dm-2                  o.e.g.b.e.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyServiceManager  Dependency factory org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.MandatoryImporterDependencyFactory@af08a49 threw exception while detecting dependencies for beanFactory org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6b35958b: defining beans [.org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceCollectionProxyFactoryBean#0,classLoaderService,resourceLocator,kernelConfigService,httpServiceConfigurationTypeHandler,.org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#0,classloaderServiceBinder,webServiceRegister,httpService,OSGIServiceExporter,.org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceCollectionProxyFactoryBean#0#0,wsInvokeListenerManager,.com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesInvokeListenerManager#0,blueprintBundle,blueprintBundleContext,blueprintContainer,blueprintConverter]; root of factory hierarchy in OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=com.hp.atom.wssupport, config=bundleentry://179.fwk1169375526/OSGI-INF/blueprint/beans.xml) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '.org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceCollectionProxyFactoryBean#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.config.internal.adapter.OsgiServiceLifecycleListenerAdapter] while setting bean property 'listeners' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister] for bean with name 'webServiceRegister' defined in OSGi resource[bundleentry://179.fwk1169375526/OSGI-INF/blueprint/beans.xml|bnd.id=179|bnd.sym=com.hp.atom.wssupport]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister not found from bundle [com.hp.atom.wssupport]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.MandatoryImporterDependencyFactory.getServiceDependencies(MandatoryImporterDependencyFactory.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyServiceManager.doFindDependencies(DependencyServiceManager.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyServiceManager.findServiceDependencies(DependencyServiceManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.activator.LifecycleManager$1.run(LifecycleManager.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm.ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor$2.run(ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister] for bean with name 'webServiceRegister' defined in OSGi resource[bundleentry://179.fwk1169375526/OSGI-INF/blueprint/beans.xml|bnd.id=179|bnd.sym=com.hp.atom.wssupport]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister not found from bundle [com.hp.atom.wssupport]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister] for bean with name 'webServiceRegister' defined in OSGi resource[bundleentry://179.fwk1169375526/OSGI-INF/blueprint/beans.xml|bnd.id=179|bnd.sym=com.hp.atom.wssupport]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister not found from bundle [com.hp.atom.wssupport]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.config.internal.adapter.OsgiServiceLifecycleListenerAdapter.initialize(OsgiServiceLifecycleListenerAdapter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.config.internal.adapter.OsgiServiceLifecycleListenerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(OsgiServiceLifecycleListenerAdapter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister not found from bundle [com.hp.atom.wssupport]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.ExtendedClassNotFoundException: com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister in KernelBundleClassLoader: [bundle=com.hp.atom.wssupport_3.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:97)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:146)

Comment: this is beans.xml file's content:
<reference-list member-type="service-reference"
  availability="optional" interface="com.hp.atom.kernel.WebServicesSupport">
  <reference-listener ref="webServiceRegister"
   bind-method="addWebServicesSupport" unbind-method="removeWebServicesSupport" />
 </reference-list>

Comment: <bean id="webServiceRegister" class="com.hp.atom.wssupport.internal.WebServicesRegister">
  <argument index="0" ref="httpService" />
  <argument index="1" ref="httpServiceConfigurationTypeHandler" />
 </bean>

Comment: Please try to format this, it's unreadable. If you give the impression of not caring, then nobody will care enough to answer.